# Bash Shell Script to iterate over folders within folder and copy files

Tags: shell, file-copying

I want to iterate over multiple directories within a directory and copy a specific csv file to different location. My shell script knowledge is at a starter level. I found couple of [solutions](https://superuser.com/questions/142220/bash-shell-scripting-how-to-iterate-through-directories-and-copy-and-rename-f) similar to what I am thinking of doing, but the problem is in my case sub directory name is not same.

Here is the structure: I have root directory `~/2013-03-03/`

Then I have following directories, I have only put few, but I have close to 300 sub directories.

```
ab   bar      ch   eml      gn   iu   kv       mhr     ne   pfl       sc   sw   ug                   zea
ace  bat-smg  chr  ext      got  jbo  kw       mi      nov  pi        scn  szl  ur                   zh-classical
af   bcl      chy  ff       gu   kaa  ky       ml      nrm  pih       sco  tet  ve                   zh-min-nan
ak   bh       ckb  fiu-vro  gv   kab  lad      mn      nso  pnb       sd   tg   vec                  zh-yue
als  bi       co   fj       ha   kbd  lbe      mo      nv   pnt       se   ti   vep
```

Each of these directories have hundred(s) of csv files where the csvfile name starts with the name of the directory. But I am only interest in one specific csv file. Assume that name is mycsvfile.csv. I want to copy this file from each subdir to a different directory in `~/2013-03-03/new_dir`

Answer (score 4):

```
find ~/2013-03-03/ -name 'mycsvfile.csv' -exec cp {} ~/2013-03-03/new_dir/ \;
```

If the files are named `subfoldername/subfoldername-mycsvfile.csv`, use something like:

```
find ~/2013-03-03/ -regextype posix-awk -regex '.*/([^/]*)/\1-mycsvfile.csv' -exec cp {} ~/2013-03-03/new_dir/ \;
```

... I always struggle what flavor regex can do what and how, this seems to work

Comment: what if the csv file name is changinging example subdirname-mycsvfile.csv

Comment: I added this to the question.

Comment: That makes it a lot different, added it an answer, but I'm less sure this is an optimal solution.

Answer (score 2):

There's probably many ways to accomplish that. Here's one relatively simple one:

```
cd ~/2013-03-03
/bin/ls -1 */mycsvfile.csv | cpio -dump ~/2013-03-03/new_dir/.
```